# AFNetworking get Parameters from Operation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, httprequest, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am attempting to get the parameters for a POST request sent via the AFNetworking pod. However, I can't seem to get them. I am looping through the active operations with the below:

```
for(AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation in manager.operationQueue.operations){
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.request.URL.path);
    }
```

However, I can't get the parameters. I've tried using `operation.request.URL.parameterString`, but since it is POST, the string is null. Anyone know how to get these? I'd like to collect them so that I can cancel requests that are specific to the path and parameters sent, ensuring I'll get down to just the single request I need to cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going about this a different way. I created a class that handled all the AFNetworking path calls. In this class is a dictionary which stored an integer id for the call and the operation. As the operations complete or fail, they are removed. The integer id is passed back to the calling object, allowing for unique access for canceling requests or polling.